# PowerShell - Formatting XML Output

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing

Good evening!  I'm attempting to use PowerShell to read in an XML file and then output the selected nodes in a specific way.  I'm nearly there, but after much research, I am stumped.

Please consider the following:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <registryKeys>
    <registryKey keyName="HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\TestKey1" owner="false">
      <registryValue name="TestValueName1" valueType="REG_EXPAND_SZ" value="TestValue1" operationHint="replace" owner="true" />
      <registryValue name="TestValueName2" valueType="REG_SZ" value="TestValue2"     operationHint="replace" owner="true" />
    </registryKey>
    <registryKey keyName="HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\TestKey2" owner="false">
      <registryValue name="TestValueName3" valueType="REG_EXPAND_SZ" value="TestValue3" operationHint="replace" owner="true" />
      <registryValue name="TestValueName4" valueType="REG_SZ" value="TestValue4" operationHint="replace" owner="true" />
    </registryKey>
  </registryKeys>
'@

$regKeyNode=$xml.SelectNodes("/registryKeys/registryKey")

foreach ($registryKey in $regKeyNode) {
    $keyname = $registrykey.keyName
    $name = $registryKey.registryValue.name
    $value = $registryKey.registryValue.value
    $namevalue =  $name+"="+$value
    Write-Host "Write-Host Line: $keyname"
    Write-Host "Write-Host Line: $namevalue"
}
```

Upon running the above code, I receive the following output:

```
Write-Host Line:  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\TestKey1
Write-Host Line:  TestValueName1 TestValueName2 = TestValue1 TestValue2
Write-Host Line:  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\TestKey2
Write-Host Line:  TestValueName3 TestValueName4 = TestValue3 TestValue4
```

This is not how I want the returned output to be formatted.  I need it to rather return like this:

```
Write-Host Line:  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\TestKey1
Write-Host Line:  TestValueName1 = TestValue1
Write-Host Line:  TestValueName2 = TestValue2
Write-Host Line:  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\TestKey1
Write-Host Line:  TestValueName3 = TestValue3
Write-Host Line:  TestValueName4 = TestValue4
```

I realize I am probably over thinking this, but for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Anyone able to simplify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the output for `$regkeynode`

```
keyName                    owner                      registryValue             
-------                    -----                      -------------            
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID... false                      {TestValueName1, TestV...
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID... false                      {TestValueName3, TestV...
```

We can see here that `RegistryValue` is an array and can hold multiple values so when you call `$registrykey.registryvalue.name` you are getting every name at the same time, if there are 10 names you are getting 10 names at once not each one individually.

One more ForEach should fix this though

First we go through each `$registrykey` to get the `$keyname`
Then each `$registryvalue` getting the `$registryvalue.name` and `$registryvalue.value`

Sample code for you to play with

```
foreach ($registryKey in $regKeyNode)
{
    $keyname = $registrykey.keyName
    Write-Host "Write-Host Line: $keyname"

    foreach ($registryValue in $registryKey.registryValue)
    {
        $name = $registryValue.Name
        $value = $registryValue.value
        $namevalue =  $name+"="+$value
        Write-Host "Write-Host Line: $namevalue"
    }
}
```